# Drupal 7 only works with index.php in url. Want to use friendly clean url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, drupal-7, clean-urls

Installed drupal 7 in **rhel** server. I can able to access the pages with index.php. Without index.php, page is redirecting to 404. My root application folder is var/www/html/sivaraj

> sivaraj.com/index.php/profile - **works fine**
>
> sivaraj.com/profile - **getting 404**

mode_rewrite is enabled in apache.

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride None
   Allow From All
   Require All Granted
</Directory>
```

When change **AllowOverride** to **All** gives **Internal Server Error 500**

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride None
   Allow From All
   Require All Granted
</Directory>
```

Didn't change anything in drupal default .htaccess. Tried with **RewriteRule** to remove index.php nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

try to change **AllowOverride None** to **AllowOverride All**
Also Apache should be restarted afterwards